# Ember ActiveModelAdapter customization

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My Ember application interacts with an API (through a DS.ActiveModelAdapter adapter) which respond to `GET "/api/v1/users?username=mcclure.rocio"` with a JSON like:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Rocio McClure",
    "username": "mcclure.rocio",
    "email": "rocio.mcclure@yahoo.com"
  }
}
```

My router is:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route("login");
  this.route("user", {path: "user/:username"}, function() {
    this.route("profile");
  });
});
```

So I have route like `http://localhost:4200/user/mcclure.rocio` which is kind of summary of a user.

The problem is loading the correct model in the route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', { username: params.username })
  }
});
```

My Ember inspector states that the loaded model is an empty *DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray*. That's because findQuery (which is actually called as I provide a query object) expect to fetch a JSON array while my API return a single *user* JSON object, so it translates it to an empty array.

However `this.store.find('user', { username: params.username })` build the right request to my API but how can I make the Store accept the API response and serve it as model to my route?

note:
If my API returned an array a could do something like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', { username: params.username }).then(function(data){
      return data.objectAtContent(0);
    });
  }
});
```

but, I prefer not to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the [normalizePayload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizePayload) function on DS.RestSerializer to modify the response to the format Ember Data expects.

Comment: thanks! Making normalizePayload return an array (`return {users:[payload.user]}`) let me use the strategy reported in my note.